# Run flask application and continue running script

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a simple flask application:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    text = '<h2>Text: </h2><form><input name="firstname" type="text">'
    select = '<h2>Select: </h2><select name="cars">' + \
              '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>' + \
              '<option value="saab">Saab</option>' + \
              '<option value="fiat">Fiat</option> ' + \
              '<option value="audi">Audi</option>' + \
            '</select>'
    multiselect = '<h2>Multiselect: </h2><select name="mCars" multiple>' + \
              '<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>' + \
              '<option value="saab">Saab</option>' + \
              '<option value="fiat">Fiat</option> ' + \
              '<option value="audi">Audi</option>' + \
            '</select>'
    textarea = '<h2>Textarea: </h2><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">' + \
                'The cat was playing in the garden.' + \
                '</textarea>'
    button = '<h2>Button</h2><button type="button" onclick="alert(\'Hello World!\')">Click Me!</button>'
    # datalist = '<h2>Datalist</h2><datalist id="browsers">' + \
    #               '<option value="Internet Explorer">' + \
    #               '<option value="Firefox">' + \
    #               '<option value="Chrome">' + \
    #               '<option value="Opera">' + \
    #               '<option value="Safari">' + \
    #             '</datalist> '
    return '<h1>Sample Form</h1>' + \
           text + \
           select + \
           multiselect + \
           textarea + \
           button


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run the file itself it runs:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I'm trying to run it from a runner file and continue execution of the file. It stops executing when flask runs. I've tried the following.

```
os.system('python ' + get_driver_file_path(Settings.TestProjectPath))
```

I think this makes sense because I am just running it.

I tried and it also runs but stops execution:

```
subprocess.call([Settings.PythonExecutablePath, get_driver_file_path(Settings.TestProjectPath)])
```

I tried:

```
server = Popen(get_driver_file_path(Settings.TestProjectPath), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
```

This does not seem to do anything.

How can I get it to run the flask server and continue execution?

Comment: How are you running this in production? Are you using `gunicorn`? Specifically, what is the command you would execute to run the app as blocking?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot There is no production yet. We are setting up a test framework and are using flask to get the gherkin test runner working. I'm just trying to run a script that will have flask app run followed by opening up some browsers with selenium and navigating to the page.

Comment: So you're probably running this with env variables like`FLASK_APP=api.py`, `FLASK_ENV=production`, `FLASK_DEBUG=0` and finally calling `flask run`, is that correct?

Comment: I am using the default env variables that flask comes with. In the script above it's called using `app = Flask(__name__)` then `app.run()` in the script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to keep **&** to run application in background

```
import os
os.system("python "+ "app.py &" )
print "hello, its working, flask is running backgound "
```

for windows

```
import os
os.system("start /b python app.py")
print("It works..!")
```

make sure that python is added to PATH

Comment: os.system('python ' + get_driver_file_path(Settings.TestProjectPath)+ " &")

Comment: I suppose it's not going to work on Windows. You may also have trouble if `python` is not on `PATH` for some reason.

Comment: solution should be platform agnostic

Answer (score 1):

I ran `subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'app.py'])` successfully on my local machine, so this should technically work. The only thing I'm not sure of is that I ran this in a terminal, and closing the terminal might have closed the subprocess too.

Comment: @DavidTunnell the docs https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api say that you shouldn't use PIPE or the child processes may block. What if you try without?

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to run a Flask app *and then* continue your script.

Actually you want to *start* the Flask app, and continue your script while it is running.

I suppose [`multiprocessing` "spawn"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is what you need to start the Flask app.

You may need to wait until the new process (e.g. listening on `localhost:5000`) actually starts to serve requests if your script's later steps depend on it running.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from threading import Thread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=app.run).run()
    print("App is running")
```